# How fast would you have to go to claim you saw the red light as green due to the Doppler Effect?

Tags: visible-light, speed-of-light, doppler-effect

Driving toward it, I suspect you would have to be going at relativistic speeds.

Calculating this, it appears to be around 1/6 the speed of light when driving directly at it, but since you are on the road and it is in the air, I can't calculate the angle well.

This could make for a good excuse to the cops :)

Comment: What have you done to try to figure this out yourself?

Comment: See edit. @David Z

Comment: The angle is not an issue, since you would be thousands of miles away.  And you would most certainly have to admit to exceeding the speed limit.

Comment: I remember this was a practice problem in my Physics class in HS. The answer was "I'm not giving you a ticket because you passed a red traffic light, but man that speeding ticket will be something!"

Comment: @ writing thesis plus all the destruction :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Randall Munroe answered this question in this article](https://what-if.xkcd.com/14/)

Let me (try) to quote:

> **How fast would you have to go in your car to run a red light claiming
>   that it appeared green to you due to the Doppler Effect?** *—Yitzi
>   Turniansky*

As expected, quoting and mathjaxing are two things that do not go together well, the rest of this post should be considered a quote:

$$\frac{Red ~light~ wavelength}{Green~ light~ wavelength}=\sqrt{\frac{1+\frac{Your ~speed}{Speed~ of~ light}}{1−\frac{Car~ speed}{Speed~ of~ light}}}$$

$$Car speed=\frac{c×(Red ~light~ wavelength²−Green~ light~ wavelength²)}{Green~ light~ wavelength²+Red~ light~ wavelength²}≈\frac16c$$

*Solely for your amusement I'd like to point out how happy I felt when finally getting this formula right and how quickly that feeling diminished when I realized I could have simply copy & pasted the mathjax code from the page source. duuuh*

Comment: @zeldredge  I deleted  the comment since the answer was edited